# Hadoop setup ubuntu Name Node, Data Node not working-jps

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

I was trying to set up Hadoop single node cluster on my pc with Ubuntu 12.10. with reference to [tutorial on Michael-noll.com](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)

- Everything went smooth till I executed '**/usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh**' command
- After that I executed java process status "**/usr/local/hadoop$ jps**"

Then I found that the `Data Node`, `Task Tracker`, `Name Node` are not listed (ie not working)

can any one help in this situation.

Comment: Without the error messages, no one would be able to help you !!!

Comment: If you followed the installation instructions, all log output should be available in /usr/local/hadoop/logs. Please look at the log files and post relevant stacktraces if you need assistence in interpreting these.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your core-site.xml file

```
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/home/rlk/hduser</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: Oh dude.. this answer saved my life. When I had localhost:9000 it didnt work.. thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Format the name node and again start all services with `start-all.sh` command and check the status of working with `jps`. This may occur if you quit the application without stopping the services. So, Before you quit from application make sure you have stopped all the service with `stop-all.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Well, I think you  install Hadoop to `/usr/local/hadoop`
2. When you run `start-all.sh`, hadoop will write log to `/usr/local/hadoop/logs` directory,
   However, maybe Hadoop doesn't have write permission to this directory.
3. Please check all log files in `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/` and find whether the problem.
4. How to solve it?

   4.1 Modify `/usr/local/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh`, i.e. 
      add `export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=/tmp/hadoop/logs`

   4.2 Restart Hadoop, and jps again, and check log files
5. I suggest you post related log here if you meet some problem again.:)

Answer (score 0):

You should have write permissions on directory which you mention in `core-site.xml` for property `hadoop.tmp.dir`. I have explained this in this link [Hadoop Series Single Node Installation.](http://lets-do-something-big.blogspot.in/2014/01/hadoop-series-single-node-installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Package Verification**

1. `$ rpm ­‐ql hadoop-­‐0.20-­‐conf-­‐pseudo`

**Format NameNode**

2. `sudo ­‐u hdfs hdfs namenode-­‐format`
3. `$
   for
   service
   in`
   /etc/init.d/hadoop*
   `>
   do
   >
   sudo
   $service
   stop
   >
   done`

**Start HDFS**

4. Start HDFS

   `$
   for
   service
   in
   /etc/init.d/hadoop-­‐hdfs-­‐*
   >
   do
   >
   sudo
   $service
   start
   >
   done`

**Change Localhost property**

5.change localhost property
    http://localhost:50070
     By following above steps you can start your namenode and datanode services.

Comment: Can you modify your answer? Grey background is only for _code_!